# In ubuntu matlab execution file cannot be run

Tags: 12.04, chmod, matlab, execute-command

I have stored my matlab installation in one of the partitions.But ubuntu doesn't recognize the matlab file as an executable file even after executing chmod +x command. Kindly help me to resolve the problem

Comment: **.exe** files which are native to Windows will not run on a Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you are trying to run a Windows version of Matlab, which is not possible.

On your Matlab CD is an installer for the Linux version, use that one.

Comment: Its a linux version only. The same version runs in other laptop having linux. My doubt is whether it will run only if I keep matlab installation file in home folder.